# How to add Linux Qt version to a generic linux device kit on Mac?

Tags: c++, linux, macos, qt, cross-compiling

I need to cross compile project with Qt5 on mac to Linux x86-64. I built the cross compiler using crosstool-ng and it works with simple "Hello World!" programmes. Also, I installed  Qt5 using official offline Linux installer on the Linux machine. I created case-sensitive volume on my mac (sysroot) and copied to there `/usr`, `/lib` and `/home/crefrod/Qt5.10.0` keeping directory structure. In QtCreator, I added `Generic Linux Device` kit and set cross-compilers for C and C++, sysroot and GDB. As I understand, this is enough to build, deploy, and debug a non-Qt project. But I need to include Qt headers, link Qt libraries and use all QtCreator's nice features for Qt like Designer. I theory, I could add Qt version for Mac, add Mac target, that I'll never use because the executable is built for Linux and linked with Linux .SO's, and link the Linux Qt in my sysroot manually through CMakeLists.txt file (assuming headers are same for all platforms). Is this a solution and are there any other, better ways?

Comment: Why not use a virtual machine (host mac, guest Linux) and build using the native tool chain(s).

Comment: The target device is an SBC (Single Board Computer) with Intel RealSense camera installed and used by the program. Now I use CLion and compile it remotely, using a build script. I use `if (UNIX AND NOT APPLE)` in CMakeLists.txt to include different folders on mac (for IntelliSense) and on Linux. CLion reads include directories directly from CMake, so it works. But I need to add a simple GUI to my program, so I decided to move to QtCreator and set up cross-compile for faster compilation and better integration in IDE. Also, I think that QtCreator will work faster, than CLion.